# page refresh not working in angular 4 in mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, routes

I am using Angular 4 in MVC application and page refresh doesn't reload the same page. I searched a lot on web and got useful info too, still not able to figure out the root cause. There is something wrong with my routing configuration and would really appreciate if someone helps in correcting it.

Project Structure : I have kept angular related files in 'client' folder, which is directly under the root directory.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <base href="/client/">

    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
enter code here
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/client/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>

        System.import('main.js').catch(function (err)
        {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/client/"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

// angular routes in app.component.html

```
const routes: Routes = [

{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, 
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [ LoggedInGaurd]  },
{ path: 'search-history', component: SearchHistoryComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGaurd] },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
```

// RouteConfig.cs

`routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new
            {
                serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraints(url =>
                {
                    return url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/Account/",
                        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                })
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "angular",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Comment: I have kept the <app-root> tag in HomeController/Index view. So, when app starts the angular home page is shown and the url forms as http://localhost:8632/client/home and then if I do page refresh, I get error message 404.